# jquery function working in one page but not working on another in a same project

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am very new to jquery and I was stuck in a jquery function for keyup. I figured it out correctly and following is the code that worked for me

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $('#txtname').keyup(function () {
            var name = $('#txtname').val();

            var lbl = $('#lbl1').text();
            var lbl2 = $("#<%=label1.ClientID %>").text();

            document.getElementById('txtdetails').value = parseInt(document.getElementById('txtname').value) * parseFloat(lbl2);

        });

    });


</script>



<input type="text" id="txtname" runat="server" />
<p><b>Keyup Event Example</b></p>
<input type="text" id="txtdetails" runat="server" />
         <asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server">20.5</asp:Label>
```

It works fine for me but when am implementing this same in another page then this is not working...in that page I have used some other jquery libraries also...is that the reason???

This is really weird and am stuck into this for a long...any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check HTML may be lbl1 id is changed in other page

Comment: have checked it..its the same...

Comment: ok, I am not able to see ibl1 in you posted html, but you have checked then its ok, if you have used other jquery library then write this script block at the bottom of page and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forcing the inputs to run at server. Which means its Id at client side might not be same as you have used.

For this you need to use the textbox.ClientID as you have used for the label.

Comment: but this code is working fine only the problem is its not working in the other page

Comment: Try finding the id of the inputs from page source. Is it same as you have written in the jQuery?

Comment: okay figured out the issue...if i use runat="server" then its not working so how to resolve it???

Comment: Instead of `$('#txtname').keyup(function ().. `  use `$('#<%txtname.ClientId%>').keyup(function ()...` and so on